# Filtering solutions using the Select function

Tags: list-manipulation, parallelization, filtering, code-request

I have a certain code that output in the following format:

```
{{a1,b1},{a2,b2},{a3,b3},...,{an,bn}}
```

Where $a_1$ and $b_1$ etc are numbers. Now I want to filter those numbers, the second number must be bigger or equal to $1$. So when I have:

```
{{0,6},{3,0},{4,1},{9,0}}
```

I need to get:

```
{{0,6},{4,1}}
```

When I have just one number I can use `Select[{1, 2, 4, 7, 6, 2, 0, 4, 5, 0}, # >= 1 &]` but how do I implement this when I have two numbers like `{a,b}` and I need to filter for $b\ge1$.

Comment: `#[[1]] >= 1 && #[[2]] >= 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Denoting your `List` as `list`:

```
Select[Last@#>=1&][list]
```

> ```
> {{0,6},{4,1}}
> ```